# Unexpected end of file error at comment line

Tags: python, syntax, eof

I was working on a problem and came across a syntax error for a print statement. I started commenting out lines and have an EOF error for a comment line. Any clue how to fix this EOF error for comments?

I've tried commenting out the lines, deleting the lines and typing them again in case I had a typo, and looking up similar solutions

Here is what I am currently trying to run:

```
# np_baseball is available

# Import numpy
import numpy as n

# Create np_height_in from np_baseball
np_height_in = np_baseball[0]
print(n.median(np_height_in))
# Print out the mean of np_height_in
print(n.mean(np_height_in)
#print(n.median(np_height_in))
# Print out the median of np_height_in
```

Here's the current error:

File "", line 12
    # Print out the median of np_height_in
                                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: missing closing parenthesis on line 10

Comment: `print(n.mean(np_height_in)`.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(n.mean(np_height_in)
```

is missing a closing `)` . It should be:

```
print(n.mean(np_height_in))
```